# How can I create an image mask tensor from unknown number of bounding boxes?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to fill zeros inside the bounding boxes of an image in TensorFlow. To be specific, I'm trying to implement `create_mask_from_bounding_boxes(image, boxes)` function in the following code.

```
# Tensor <?, 4>, where each element contains [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]
boxes

# Tensor <H, W, C>
image

# Tensor <H, W, C>
mask = create_mask_from_bounding_boxes(image, boxes)

# mask out bounding boxes in the image
bounding_box_masked_image = mask * image
```

If the number of boxes were available, I would have done something like this:

```
def create_mask_from_bounding_boxes(image, boxes):
    mask = tf.zeros_like(image)
    for box in tf.unstack(boxes):
        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tf.unstack(box)
        mask[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax] = 1
    return mask
```

However, since the number of boxes is unavailable, I can't use `tf.unstack(boxes)`. Is there any other way to create an image mask from unknown number of bounding boxes in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3):

The general answer to "what to do when I have unknown shape?" question is "Use [TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray)". TensorArray gives a way of dealing with statically unknown number of Tensors.

Here are a couple of ways of addressing your specific question:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

USE_FOLD = True

def box_mask(box):
  """Create a 4x4 tensor of zeros except for a rectangle of ones defined by `box`"""
  x, y = 4, 4
  ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tf.unstack(box)
  h = xmax - xmin
  z0 = tf.zeros([xmin, y])
  z1 = tf.concat(
      [tf.zeros([h, ymin]),
       tf.ones([h, ymax - ymin]),
       tf.zeros([h, y - ymax])],
      axis=1)
  z2 = tf.zeros([x - xmax, y])
  return tf.concat([z0, z1, z2], axis=0)

def reduce_mask(a, box):
  mask = box_mask(box)
  return tf.maximum(a, mask)

def main():
  boxes_val = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 2], [2, 2, 4, 4]])
  boxes = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.int32)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    if USE_FOLD:
      print sess.run(tf.foldl(reduce_mask, boxes,
                              initializer=tf.zeros([4,4])),
                     feed_dict={boxes: boxes_val})
    else:
      masks = tf.map_fn(box_mask, boxes, dtype=tf.float32)
      combined_mask = tf.reduce_max(masks, axis=0)
      print sess.run(combined_mask, feed_dict={boxes: boxes_val})
```

I hard-coded the image size to 4x4 for simplicity. Both approaches use functional primitives: `tf.map_fn` and `tf.foldl`. These primitives are built upon `tf.while_loop` and `TensorArray`. The approach with `USE_FOLD-True` might be slower because each box is transformed to a mask and applies to current mask sequentially, but requires less memory - independent of the number of boxes. The approach with `USE_FOLD=False` does conversions from boxes to masks in parallel, followed by a single reduction step (`or`ing all masks together). However, it requires memory proportional to `image_size * num_boxes`.

The memory vs speed discussion is probably moot in this examples, since conversion from box to mask is quite fast. But can be important if "the map portion" of the computation is expensive.